# How fill a UITableViewCell with multiple UILabel using auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

i have a `UITableViewCell` that contains some `UILabel` and i want that this label fill horizontally the width of the `UITableViewCell` and that doesn't remains big space instead of other, this is an example:

```
|---------------------------------------------------------
|                                                        |
|***This is a uilabel***This is a uilabel***label***lb** |
|                                                        |
|---------------------------------------------------------
```

So with different `UILabel` width i want that all the `UILabel` fill all the `UITableViewCell` fixing the font size if needed, the * is the spacing, how i can achieve this with auto layout?

Comment: are you using IB or code constraints?

Comment: i'm using Interface Builder

Comment: @PIERO couldn't understand ur problem pls make it more clear.

Answer (score 5):

### STEP 1: Set up constraints

**Leftmost label**: Add a leading edge constraint and a center Y constraint to its superview

**Middle labels**: Add a horizontal spacing and center Y constraint to previous label.

**Rightmost label**: Add a horizontal spacing and center Y constraint to previous label *plus* a trailing edge constraint to superview.

These constraints ensure the gaps between the labels and on the left and right are fixed in size, and that they are all centered in their superview. Because there are no width constraints, the layout system will attempt to size them to fit their content. *But this leaves an ambiguity...*

### STEP 2: Set content size priorities.

The above constraints are still ambiguous -

1. If the total text content is *less* than the superview's width, which label will *expand* bigger than its content?
2. If the total text content is *more* than the superview's width, which label will *contract* shrinking its content to fit?

The answer to the first question is the label with the lowest *horizontal content hugging priority*. By default they will all have the same, so make sure they have different horizontal content hugging priorities.

The answer to the second question is the label with the lowest *horizontal content compression resistance priority*. By default they will all have the same, so make sure they have different horizontal content compression resistance priorities.

### STEP 3: Ensure text shrinks to fit.

We now have an unambiguous layout. But by default, the labels will truncate their content if they do not have room to display it. Set *Autoshrink* to *Minimum Font Scale* or *Minimum Font Size* on your labels to ensure they adjust font size to fit their content rather than truncating it.